# Building a deployable WAR based on a spring-boot project

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying create a WAR file from a Spring-boot project, which allow the user either run the file with `java -jar filename` and deploy this file with tomcat.

Right now, I have this configuration:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>springapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Application.java**

```
package org.hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package org.hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

with this configuration, I am be able to run the application in the command line with `java -jar filename`, but when I deploy the war in the tomcat, I get a 404 error page when I access the / page. (No error is displayed when the application is deployed).

What I am missing here?

Comment: What's the full URL that you're using to access the app when it's deployed to Tomcat and what's the name of the war file?

Comment: the full url is `http://server:8080/springapp-1.0.0` and the war file is `springapp-1.0.0.war`.

Comment: You say no error is displayed. What else is displayed? You should see output in Tomcat's logs showing the war being deployed and your application starting up – Spring Boot's banner, etc.

Comment: in the file `/var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out` the only line display after the deploy is: `Oct 15, 2015 11:38:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
// INFO: Deploying web application archive springapp-1.0.0.war`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot requires your container to support Servlet 3.0 or later. Tomcat 6 only supports Servlet 2.5. The easiest option is to upgrade to Tomcat 7 or 8.

If you can't upgrade to Tomcat 7 or 8, then it's still possible to get your app running. However, it'll require a bit more effort. As [described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-servlet-2-5), you need to add a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-legacy` and add a `web.xml` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>demo.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: where I should put this web.xml file in the my project's tree? maybe /src/main/resources?